# Trying to upload a file with ftp using azure functions

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-functions

I am trying to send a file using external file protocol and FTP api connection. The configuration and code is straight forwards and the app runs successfully however no data is sent to the FTP and I cannot see any trace that the function even tried to send data using ftp.... What is wrong? and more important; Where can i monitor the progress of the external file api?

My code follows (Note: I have tried Stream and string as input and output)

run.csx

```
public static void Run(Stream myBlobInput, string name, out Stream 
 myFTPOutput, TraceWriter log)
    {
        myFTPOutput = myBlobInput;
        //log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Content:{myBlob}");
        log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size:{myBlobInput.Length} \n Content:{myBlobInput.ToString()}");

    }
```

function.json

```
"bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlobInput",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "input/{name}",
      "connection": "blob_STORAGE"
    },
    {
      "name": "myFTPOutput",
      "type": "apiHubFile",
      "direction": "out",
      "path": "/output/{name}",
      "connection": "ftp_FTP"

    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Comment: Why dont you do it using a logic app? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sftp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I changed the ftp Connection to some other server and it work like a charm. That means that there were some firewall refusal from the Azure Function that triggered. The sad thing is that no error messages triggers that i can spot. Thanks for all support

Answer (score 0):

I could make it working :
If we want to have same file content in the output FTP server and same file name ,then here is the code and function.json

```
public static void Run(string myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log , out string outputFile )
{
log.Info($"2..C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size:{myBlob.Length} \n Content:{myBlob.ToString()}");
outputFile=myBlob;
}
```

Also here is the function.json

```
    {
      "bindings": [
        {
          "name": "myBlob",
          "type": "blobTrigger",
          "direction": "in",
          "path": "myblobcontainer/{name}",
          "connection": "AzureWebJobsDashboard"
        },
        {
          "type": "apiHubFile",
          "name": "outputFile",
          "path": "LogFiles/{name}",
          "connection": "ftp_FTP",
          "direction": "out"
        }
      ],
      "disabled": false
    }
```

the input binding should have a valid container name as in blob account here--:
[blob container structure as path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZLXE.png)

Also in output binding for FTP, the path should be any folder in Root of FTP , what you see in FTP login UI/console and then filename , which in this case {name} ,which allows us to keep the same output file name as input blob name.

Comment: I tried your example and it executes just as fine as my code specified does, that is azure function completes on blob trigger and logs the content of the blob/and or stats of the blob. However no file i present in the remote FTP-server. Hence makes me believe that the Connection is bad, however the api connection seems correct in azure portal, with trace of successful setup, yet no trace of any other activities. Any ideas?